# Building Geonetwork

Tags: maven, maven-2, dependencies, geonetwork

I have downloaded the Geonetwork and am trying to build it through maven.But I am getting the following error and am not able to resolve it

```
  Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
```

javac: invalid target release: 1.7
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options

```
at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:729)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
```

[ERROR]

I think the error is because of inclusion of certain packages.How to resolve that?

Can anyone suggest anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely not running java 7 on your machine but one of the poms is specifying that java 1.7 is required:

```
<target>1.7</target>
```

You should upgrade your machine to java 1.7 if possible. Or figure out which dependency requires java 1.7 and determine if you need that dependency.

Comment: No. I am running java 7 only.The version is java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Just to be sure, can you do a mvn -v and verify the java version

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me... I changed the target to 1.6.Actually Javac version was 1.6